# Promise - return data to constant with async / await function

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am trying to understand `knex` and have created the following example service layer for it:

```
const config = require('../db/knexfile');
const env = 'development';
const knex = require('knex')(config[env]);

/**
 * Return all posts
 */
function getAllPosts() {
    return knex('posts').select().then(data => {
        return data
    })
}

/**
 * Create a post
 */
function create(title, description) {
    console.log("Titel: " + title + " Description: " + description)

    return knex('posts')
        .insert({
            title: title,
            description: description,
            deleted: true,
            createdAt: new Date(),
            updatedAt: new Date()
        }, 'id')
        .then(id => {
            console.log("Inserted post with id "+ id)            
            return id;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

/**
 * find a post by id
 */
function findById(id) {
    try {
        return knex('posts').select().where('id', id).first().then(data => {
            return data
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    create,
    getAllPosts,
    findById
}
```

I am calling the above file from another file:

```
const service = require('./t5_0-serviceLayer')

async function main() {

    //prepare data
    //service.prepareData()

    //getAll
    service.getAllPosts().then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    })

    //create
    const id = service.create("Test post", "Test description")
    console.log("Post with " + id + ": " + service.findById(id))

    //get all Posts
    const res = service.getAllPosts()
    console.log("We have " + res.length  + " posts.")


}

main().then().catch(err => console.error(err))
```

I get the following output:

```
Titel: Test post Description: Test description
Post with undefined undefined
We have undefined posts.
[{"id":43,"title":"Et saepe qui occaecati unde nesciunt et.","description":"Sint commodi possimus sunt voluptatibus rerum. Incidunt mollitia accusantium ita
que nihil tempora. Qui veritatis ipsam expedita velit aut consequatur distinctio. Veritatis culpa labore rem ut a non perferendis.","deleted":false,"created
At":"2017-09-17T03:18:19.452Z","updatedAt":"2017-09-17T06:29:40.385Z","deletedAt":"2017-09-17T08:05:17.367Z"},{"id":44,"title":"Deserunt laborum reiciendis
magnam doloremque animi aspernatur sunt quod.","description":"Ea recusandae voluptas magni magni ipsum non dolorem iusto modi. Ipsum fuga inventore corporis
 qui. Qui voluptatum eaque nesciunt expedita sed ipsa vel dolor inventore. Quos praesentium dolorum aut et amet amet tempora sed et.","deleted":true,"create
dAt":"2017-09-16T22:23:51.956Z","updatedAt":"2017-09-17T13:46:44.679Z","deletedAt":"2017-09-17T11:09:14.936Z"},{"id":45,"title":"Quibusdam sunt qui beatae."
,"description":"Aut tempore totam. Nihil qui est rerum ut ipsum at autem sint. Pariatur tempore praesentium. Magnam doloremque ipsam. Nihil nesciunt odit bl
anditiis.","deleted":false,"createdAt":"2017-09-16T20:58:03.889Z","updatedAt":"2017-09-17T11:19:06.696Z","deletedAt":"2017-09-17T03:42:25.541Z"},{"id":46,"t
itle":"Test post","description":"Test description","deleted":true,"createdAt":"2017-09-17T17:34:12.882Z","updatedAt":"2017-09-17T17:34:12.882Z","deletedAt":
null},{"id":47,"title":"Test post","description":"Test description","deleted":true,"createdAt":"2017-09-17T17:35:54.056Z","updatedAt":"2017-09-17T17:35:54.0
56Z","deletedAt":null},{"id":48,"title":"Test post","description":"Test description","deleted":true,"createdAt":"2017-09-17T17:36:28.801Z","updatedAt":"2017
-09-17T17:36:28.801Z","deletedAt":null}]
Unhandled rejection Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST query: select * from "posts" where "id" = ? limit ?
    at QueryCompiler_PG.toSQL (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\knex\lib\query\compiler.js:131:13)
    at Builder.toSQL (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\knex\lib\query\builder.js:115:44)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:56:32
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\using.js:185:26
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Promise._fulfill (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
    at PromiseArray._resolve (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:126:19)
    at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:144:14)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_knex\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)

Inserted post with id 49
```

I am currently having the following problems with my service layer

- I am not getting the id of the created post back when I call `const id = service.create("Test post", "Test description")`
- I do not get the post length back when I call `service.getAllPosts()`

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https calls are asynchronous. The results cannot be returned you have to use the result inside the 'then' of your promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using `async` on your `main` function. You need to put `await` before each promise returning function call within `main`. I'm assuming `service.create` returns a promise? If it does, then use something like this:

```
const id = await service.create("Test post", "Test description")
```

Same goes for `service.getAllPosts`:

```
const res = await service.getAllPosts()
```

@trincot's answer isn't wrong... it just ignores the fact that you're attempting to use `async`, which is an available language feature on modern node versions. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Keep in mind that you probably want to do that in a `try/catch` block to handle any unexpected errors.

Comment: Thx for your reply! I am using `node 8.x` so this should work, however I still get the following exception: `Titel: Test post Description: Test description
Post with undefined: undefined
Unhandled rejection Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling FIRST query: select * from "posts" where "id" = ? limit ?`

Comment: In your create method, knex('posts').insert... should be returned otherwise your create function isn't returning the promise. Also, you don't need a try / catch block there... you should chain a .catch((err) => console.log(err)) after the .then` block

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on how to use Promises in JavaScript (really work on understanding all the details). Async / await builds on top of Promises, so if you haven't mastered them, async functions are just going to add even more confusion.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Would you be so kind to show me the full create method?

Comment: i'll edit your original question since that won't fit in a comment. It'll have to be approved by a peer review so it might not show up right away.

Comment: looks like the edit for the create method is available now.. see your code above. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`service.getAllPosts()` returns a promise, not the promised value. So it is not the array you were apparently expecting.

You need to keep using `then` to get access to the result that will only be available asynchronously:

```
service.getAllPosts().then(function(res) {
    console.log("We have " + res.length  + " posts.");
});
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! How can I access the `res` outside of the function?

Comment: define global variable and assign the `res` to it

Comment: You should not do that. You seem to be asking: how can I access `res` synchronously: you cannot, because it is only available later. You must stick to the Promise chain: put *everything* that depends on `res` in the `then` callback, or call it from there.

Comment: to access res or save res outside that function use ES6

    service.getAllPosts().then((res) => {
       console.log("We have " + res.length  + " posts.");
    });